# Jenkins Travis-CI build fails in cli module (shade fails)

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-shade-plugin

I am running a custom Jenkins 2.263.4 build on Travis-CI. We need a fix with relative pathes that never made it into the Jenkins core...well for us it is mandatory.

Based on release 2.263.4 I applied the fix in core/SecretRewriter.java and core/VirtualFile.java and also changed the version name to give it branding. This worked very well in the past releases. But the last update we did was one year ago.

Now I am running into the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.1:shade (default) on project cli: Error creating shaded jar: duplicate entry: META-INF/services/io.jenkins.cli.shaded.org.apache.sshd.common.io.IoServiceFactoryFactory -> [Help 1]
```

I am not able to understand it at all.

Travis-CI is here: https://travis-ci.com/github/DanielWeber/jenkins
GitHub: https://github.com/DanielWeber/jenkins

I was not able to find this exact problem from somewhere else. I tried a bit with the shade config to set

```
<minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
```

and similar small things, but didn't really help.

My change is so small, I don't really understand what's happening.
If nothing helps, I might consider doing changes step by step then, rather than just merging the releae to our for, but hope someone sees the problem.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `mvn install` and furthermore `mvn package` in your travis.yml file? this means you are running things in duplicate which slows down your build process apart from that it is not necessary nor useful and if I saw it correctly that causes the issue...

Comment: @khmarbaise I would gladly accept your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the build is being execute two times based on the `mvn install` followed by `mvn package` which is defined in `travis.yml` file. This causes the issue.